# I want to loop My file creator a certain amount of times in python

Tags: python

Here is the code i am not sure what i have to do to loop it a certain amount of times

```
#import stuff
 import os
import random
import string
#generate ran str
letters = string.ascii_lowercase
strgen = ( ''.join(random.choice(letters) for i in range(10)) )
#creating file and saving into dir
filepath = os.path.join('c:/files/' + strgen + '.txt')
if not os.path.exists('c:/files'):
    os.makedirs('c:/files')
f = open(filepath, "w+")
```

Comment: you want to execute same code certain no of times

Comment: Yeah that’s exactly what I want to do

Answer (score 0):

not sure if I got it right but do you mean something like below?

```
count = 0

while count < 10:
     letters = string.ascii_lowercase
     strgen = ( ''.join(random.choice(letters) for i in range(10)) )
     #creating file and saving into dir
     filepath = os.path.join('c:/files/' + strgen + '.txt')
     if not os.path.exists('c:/files'):
     os.makedirs('c:/files')
     f = open(filepath, "w+")         

     count = count + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Whatever action you want to perform place inside action function

start action after particular time you want to execute this function

stop interval for stop executing

No of times executing=Stop interval/set interval

import time, threading

```
StartTime=time.time()

def action() :
    print('action ! -> time : {:.1f}s'.format(time.time()-StartTime))


class setInterval :
    def __init__(self,interval,action) :
        self.interval=interval
        self.action=action
        self.stopEvent=threading.Event()
        thread=threading.Thread(target=self.__setInterval)
        thread.start()

    def __setInterval(self) :
        nextTime=time.time()+self.interval
        while not self.stopEvent.wait(nextTime-time.time()) :
            nextTime+=self.interval
            self.action()

    def cancel(self) :
        self.stopEvent.set()

# start action every 1s
inter=setInterval(0.6,action)
print('just after setInterval -> time : {:.1f}s'.format(time.time()-StartTime))

# will stop interval in 5s
t=threading.Timer(5,inter.cancel)
t.start()
```